# Compress AVAudioPCMBuffers to usable m4a data in memory for use with iOS Audio background mode

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, mp4

**Question:** How can I compress AVAudioPCMBuffers (efficiently or otherwise) on iOS to m4a format, including MPEG-4 Part 14 headers that a .m4a file needs to have, **in-memory** without touching the disk? A proper m4a file is needed because online services require it and cannot parse raw m4a audio.

**What I've tried:** (Code included at bottom of post)

- AVAudioConverter: This generates a raw m4a media buffer but there appears to be no way to wrap it in the necessary "atom" headers that constitute a usable m4a file. I spent a few hours with Apple's MPEG-4/Quicktime file documentation but hit a wall. I just can't figure out how to re-create all the necessary atoms. It's a beast. Furthermore, AVAudioConverter can seemingly handle a wide range of output sample rates. I suspect this indicates it doesn't necessarily use hardware acceleration.
- AVAssetWriter: This can only write files to disk and, what's more, *cannot* overwrite an existing file. Which means every few-second transcription in a 60 minute session will produce a new file. And it seems incredibly wasteful to hit the flash storage (write, then read back). The benefit is that this seems to use hardware accelerated encoding. It doesn't support arbitrary frequencies and seems to only work with 44.1 and 48KHz output for m4a, which is ok (not ideal since many voice models desire 16KHz).

**More context**

iOS has an Audio background mode, for e.g. music players and voice recorders. We know apps like Spotify and YouTube can receive compressed audio streams, decompress them, and play them, all while in the Audio background mode.

I have a similar use case:

- Frequently compress and *transmit* audio to a server.
- Occasionally receive and play back a response.

I'm continuously recording to a big AVAudioPCMBuffer and extracting segments that are found to contain voice (using a voice activity detector). I need to transcribe this, so I'm forced to use an online service (SFSpeech will cause the app to be suspended after ~10 minutes due to presumably too much CPU usage). This necessitates compression (to m4a).

** Code **

AVAudioConverter -> AVAudioCompressedBuffer. Works but seemingly no way to wrap this in a proper m4a header while remaining in RAM:

```
    private func prepareCompressedOutputSamples() {
        guard let audioCaptureBuffer = _audioCaptureBuffer else {
            return
        }

        var description = AudioStreamBasicDescription(
            mSampleRate: audioCaptureBuffer.format.sampleRate,
            mFormatID: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
            mFormatFlags: UInt32(MPEG4ObjectID.AAC_LC.rawValue),
            mBytesPerPacket: 0,
            mFramesPerPacket: 1024,
            mBytesPerFrame: 0,
            mChannelsPerFrame: audioCaptureBuffer.format.channelCount,
            mBitsPerChannel: 0,
            mReserved: 0
        )
        let compressedFormat = AVAudioFormat(streamDescription: &description)!

        // Lazy instantiate converter
        if _compressedConverter == nil {
            // Lazy instantiate audio converter once we know the recording format
            _compressedConverter = AVAudioConverter(from: audioCaptureBuffer.format, to: compressedFormat)
            if _compressedConverter == nil {
                print("[AudioCaptureController] Error: Unable to create compressed converter")
            } else {
                print("[AudioCaptureController] Successfully created compressed audio converter")
            }
        }

        // Lazy instantiate model input buffer when needed
        if _compressedAudioBuffer == nil {
            let numFrames = AVAudioFrameCount(ceil(_outputFormat.sampleRate * Double(_maxAudioBufferSeconds)))
            let totalBytes = numFrames * audioCaptureBuffer.format.channelCount * 4  // assume float32
            let bytesPerPacket = description.mFramesPerPacket * audioCaptureBuffer.format.channelCount * 4
            _compressedAudioBuffer = AVAudioCompressedBuffer(format: compressedFormat, packetCapacity: (totalBytes / bytesPerPacket) + 1, maximumPacketSize: _compressedConverter!.maximumOutputPacketSize)
            if _compressedAudioBuffer == nil {
                print("[AudioCaptureController] Error: Unable to create compressed audio buffer")
            } else {
                print("[AudioCaptureController] Successfully created compressed audio buffer")
            }
        }

        guard let compressedAudioBuffer = _compressedAudioBuffer, let compressedConverter = _compressedConverter else {
            return
        }

        // Perform conversion to model input format. No need to reset frameLength to 0 because this
        // function appears to always fill from the start of the buffer.
        var error: NSError?
        var allSamplesReceived = false
        compressedConverter.reset()
        compressedConverter.convert(to: compressedAudioBuffer, error: &error, withInputFrom: { (inNumPackets: AVAudioPacketCount, outError: UnsafeMutablePointer<AVAudioConverterInputStatus>) -> AVAudioBuffer? in
            // This is the input block that is called repeatedly over and over until the destination is filled
            // to capacity. But that isn't the behavior we want! We want to stop after we have converted the
            // complete input and do not want it to repeat. Hence, we have to do some ridiculous trickery to
            // stop it because whoever designed this API is a maniac. For more details see:
            // https://www.appsloveworld.com/swift/100/27/avaudioconverter-with-avaudioconverterinputblock-stutters-audio-after-processing

            if allSamplesReceived {
                outError.pointee = .noDataNow
                return nil
            }
            allSamplesReceived = true
            outError.pointee = .haveData
            return audioCaptureBuffer
        })
        if let error = error {
            print("[AudioCaptureController] Error: Unable to compress captured audio: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

AVAssetWriter solution. Works but requires writing to disk then reading back (and, not shown, either deleting the file or generating a new one each time). Is there really no way to have this thing dump to RAM?

```
public func writeFile(buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, completion: @escaping (Data?) -> Void) {
        guard let cmSampleBuffer = buffer.convertToCMSampleBuffer() else {
            print("[M4AWriter] Error: Unable to convert PCM buffer to CMSampleBuffer")
            return
        }

        guard let assetWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(outputURL: _temporaryFileURL, fileType: .m4a) else {
            print("[M4AWriter] Error: Unable to create asset writer")
            return
        }

        assetWriter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

        let audioSettings: [String: Any] = [
            AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
            AVSampleRateKey: 44100,//buffer.format.sampleRate,  //TODO: does not support 16KHz! Only 44.1 and 48 KHz (hardware encoder?)
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: buffer.format.channelCount,
            AVEncoderBitRateKey: 128000
        ]

        let audioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .audio, outputSettings: audioSettings)

        assetWriter.add(audioInput)

        if !assetWriter.startWriting() {
            print("[M4AWriter] Error: Unable to start writing: \(assetWriter.error?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown error")")
        }
        assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: .zero)
        audioInput.append(cmSampleBuffer)
        audioInput.markAsFinished()
        //assetWriter.endSession(atSourceTime: .zero)
        assetWriter.finishWriting {
            if assetWriter.status == .completed {
                print("[M4AWriter] Created m4a file successfully")
                self.loadFile(completion: completion)
            } else if assetWriter.status == .failed {
                print("[M4AWriter] Error: Failed to create m4a file: \(assetWriter.error?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown error") \(assetWriter.status)")
            } else {
                print("[M4AWriter]: Error: Failed to create m4a file")
            }
        }
    }


    private func loadFile(completion: (Data?) -> Void) {
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: _temporaryFileURL)
        completion(data)
    }
```